# watir-webdriver - chrome and IE change input when setting text_field with special characters

Tags: internet-explorer, special-characters, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to insert text into text field. It has some special characters. It turns out to be a problem in Chrome and IE.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome #or :ie
# here are some steps
field = browser.text_field
field.set "O'Reily" #this is just an example of problematic text
# after this field.value equals "O''Reily" when using chrome
```

Chrome inserts single quotation mark before my quotation mark. And it's not the only case.
When I set field with this original text:

> ~ ! ^ & ` ´ ¨ ' "

Chrome actually sets field with this value

> `~ ! ^ & `` '´ '¨ '' '"

And in IE it removes some spaces

> ~! ^& `´ ¨ ' "

Only Firefox sets field with my original text.

Can someone please help me with setting the exact text in Chrome and IE ?
Thanks.

Comment: And my versions are 
 - chromedriver_win_23.0.1240.0.zip
 - IEDriverServer_Win32_2.25.3.zip 
 - watir-webdriver 0.6.1
 - selenium-webdriver 2.25.0
 - watir 2.0.4
 - Chrome browser 22.0.1229.79 m
 - IE9 9.0.8112
 - win 7 x64

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this at the top of your files? From [Watir-General](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/watir-general/xb8d0a48uFI/5EOSewVCce4J)

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

Comment: I did try it now, but no change.

Comment: And also, because I'm calling watir from cucumber, in c:\Ruby193\bin\cucumber.bat, I've tried to use 

    @"ruby.exe" -Ku